# Simple HTML DOM - Skip certain element

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I want to ignore the contents of the `<a>` which is inside `<h3>` element and only get the text of the `<h3>`.

```
<h3>
144.000 TL
<a class="emlak-endeksi-link trackClick trackId_emlak-endeksi-link" id="emlakEndeksiLink">
Emlak Endeksi</a>
</h3>
```

Example: only want to get 144.000 TL and ignore the (Emlak Endeksi)

```
foreach ($html1->find('div.classifiedInfo h3') as $price) {
    $ilanlar['price'] = $price->plaintext;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not *very* familiar with simple html dom, but ... selecting the text node via http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#frag_find_textcomment should help?

```
$ilanlar['price'] = $price->find('text', 0)->plaintext;
```

Comment: thank you so much, @jakumi it worked for me and its the shortest way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe removing the `<a>` tag helps:

```
$str = <<<str
<h3>
144.000 TL
<a class="emlak-endeksi-link trackClick trackId_emlak-endeksi-link" id="emlakEndeksiLink">
Emlak Endeksi</a>
</h3>
str;

$html = str_get_html($str);

// Find first <h3>
$h3 = $html->find('h3', 0);

// Find first <a> inside the <h3>, or use $h3->find('a') to find all of them
$a = $h3->find('a', 0);

// Remove <a> tag
$a->outertext = '';

// Output: "144.000 TL"
print trim($h3->innertext);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via regular expression.

```
preg_match_all('\<h3>([^\n]*\n+)+<a([^\n]*\n+)+<\/h3>\', $content, $output);
echo $output[1];
```

https://regex101.com/r/qM5Nlk/1